# Can you merge entities in featuretools?

Tags: featuretools

Is it possible to merge entities in an entity set such as dataframes in pandas? Something that is the reverse of normalizing entities.

If I have the following es:

```
Entityset: transactions
  Entities:
    sessions [Rows: 35, Columns: 6]
    products [Rows: 5, Columns: 2]
    transactions [Rows: 500, Columns: 5]
  Relationships:
    transactions.product_id -> products.product_id
    transactions.session_id -> sessions.session_id
```

and I am looking for some function like this to merge entities:

```
es = es.denormalize_entity(first_entity_id="sessions",
                           second_entity_id="customers",
                           index="customer_id")
```

I would get the following output:

```
Entityset: transactions
  Entities:
    products [Rows: 5, Columns: 2]
    transactions [Rows: 500, Columns: 10]
  Relationships:
    transactions.product_id -> products.product_id
```

Comment: there is not currently a method in featuretools to do this. it could be done using pandas before loading the data into an entity set. is there a strong reason to do this within featuertools rather than as a preprocessing step before?

Comment: I'm trying to identify intermediate entities within the entityset that I could potentially eliminate by combining it with its parent entity. That is slightly evident by looking at the relationships provided in featuretools rather than depending on manual identification.

Comment: got it. would you mind filing an issue on github with this request and information about your use case? we'd be happy to look into it or accept contributions implementing it. Here is the github link: https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/issues